# How to customize touch detection in custom UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touch

Tl;DR: A `UIView` sublass draws some custom shapes into its frame. How to only respond to touches inside these shapes?

**Details:**

Assume we would like to create a custom bar chart. `BarChartView` receives some data array as input and for each item it ads a `BarView` as subview.

The frame of each `BarView` is similar to the `BarChartView`s bounds. However, most of the `BarView` is transparent, it handles drawing its bar (a simple rect) to the correct location.

Now I would like to detect touches within the bars. Not within the complete `BarView` (which covers the complete `BarChartView`) but only within the drawn bars/rects.

**How can I do this?**

`isUserInteractionEnabled` is true for the `BarChartView` and all its `BarView`s. However only the top most `BarView` does receive the touch event. How can this view tell iOS "this touch is not handled by me, pass it to the other views"?

I tried to override `hitTest` but this does not work:

```
class BarView: UIView {
    ...

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("hitTest: \(data.index)")
        
        if touchInsideBarRect(point) {
            print("   inside")
            return self  // Return self to indicate that the touch is handeled
        }
        
        return superview // Return parent BarChartView to let others BarViews handle the touch
    }
}
```

Output shows that the top most `BarView` correctly detects wether the touch was inside the bar or not. However, if the touch was outside and `superview` is returned, the other `BarView`s are not called to check if they handle the touch.

Comment: Have you try ``return nil`` on this view to pass instead of ``return superview``?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It seems that instead of `hitTets(with:)` the correct choice is `point(inside:width:)`